# Elasticsearch: Turn off logging for a single local node

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a single local node which I'm initializing and connecting to with

```
node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder ().local (true).node ();
node.start ();
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder ()
            .put ("node.local", "true").build ();
client = new TransportClient (settings)
            .addTransportAddress (new LocalTransportAddress ("1"));
```

When I use the client, there's a massive amount of debug logging that's outputted. Is there any way to disable to the logging?

Comment: I was looking in to this same thing and thought I'd link this solution I found here as well, since this question is one of the top results on google: [https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/elasticsearch/Kxt45avq6TI/w5K0SHhkGIoJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/elasticsearch/Kxt45avq6TI/w5K0SHhkGIoJ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses log4j, so just include a log4j, so just include a `log4j.properties` file to control the logging level.

For example you can have it contain only this line `log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout` to only output errors

Comment: i think it's using slf4j rather than log4j directly. i'm using logback and based on your suggestion, i added a logback config file and that stopped the debug messages. thx.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can control the logging via the config/logging.yml file for elasticsearch.

Comment: This is a local node created using the Java API. How would I use config files for it?