# Elasticsearch (Java) disable logging

Tags: java, elasticsearch, log4j, yaml

I am trying to run a local Elasticsearch instance from within Java, but it's spamming my console with all sorts of messages. This is my code to build the settings and create the node:

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", "localcluster")
            //Paths
            .put("path.data", "ESConsole/data")
            .put("path.logs", "ESConsole/logs")
            .put("path.work", "ESConsole/work")
            .put("path.plugins", "ESConsole/plugins")
            .put("path.conf", "ESConsole/config")
            //Make the node unreachable from the outside
            .put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", false)
            .put("node.local", true)
            .put("http.enabled", false)
            .build();
this.node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().settings(settings).node();
```

I have tried creating a logger.yml and log4j.properties file and set the logging level to "ERROR" (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577675/elasticsearch-turn-off-logging-for-a-single-local-node)), but that didn't seem to work (unless I did something really wrong).
Is there a simple setting I can put in the settings builder (preferably) or do I have to create a settings file?

The reason I am asking this here is because all I could find was people that said something about a config file, while I would prefer to keep everything in code. If that's not possible, please let me know ;)

Thanks!

Comment: What I've done now is just setting the log4j level to "info", that way at least it's a lot less verbose. Other than that there doesn't seem to be a nice solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I ended up doing is this:

```
    Settings settings = settingsBuilder()
            .put("http.enabled", false)
            .put("network.host", "127.0.0.1")
            .put("cluster.name", "my_cluster_name")
            .put("node.name", "my_node_name")
            .put("path.home", HOME.getAbsolutePath())
            .put("path.conf", CONFIG.getAbsolutePath())
            .put("path.logs", LOGS.getAbsolutePath())
            .build();

    // make sure ES' logging system knows where to find our custom logging.xml
    LogConfigurator.configure(settings);

    // startup a standalone node to use for tests
    return nodeBuilder()
            .settings(settings)
            .local(true)
            .loadConfigSettings(false)
            .node();
```

The key here is the `LogConfigurator.configure()` call. Note that I did have to copy a custom `logging.yml` file into the `path.logs` directory that simply disables the console logger.

I suspect if the settings included `logger.level = OFF`, then you wouldn't need a custom `logging.yml` file at all, but then you'd have zero logging (which might be what you want).

Comment: Was looking for a solution to this problem as well, I found this helped too: [https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/elasticsearch/Kxt45avq6TI/w5K0SHhkGIoJ](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/elasticsearch/Kxt45avq6TI/w5K0SHhkGIoJ)

Comment: What is the content of the custom `logging.yml`? @KoenDeGroote, link is broken.

Comment: @Velkan I ended up hardcoding it into the Java code. Added the solution I found to the end of the question.